# Interpreting truth functions in Shoenfield

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am confused about details captured in the following screen shot from “Mathematical Logic” by Shoenfield. (pdf for anyone interested: [https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/shoenfield.pdf](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/shoenfield.pdf))
[image]

The thing I am confused about in this text is the meaning of the unary truth function for negation in the right hand side of the second highlighted line. In the first highlighted line, and the line right above it, disjunction is defined by a truth function with two arguments (those being two truth values). But then in the second highlighted line it only has one argument of the one truth value, and I can’t understand the reason for this discrepancy, or how it even makes sense on its own; how could a proposition with disjunction even be well formed if it’s only taking in the truth value of one sentence?

Comment: Which aspect of the text does your question deal with?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like they've switched the places, the correct reading should be this $H_\lor(H_\neg(a),b)$.

This is likely the correct interpretation, since (i) it is consistent with the number of operands each operator is supposed to take and (ii) as mentioned in the paragraph above, the truth value of the conditional for (A,B) is exactly "NOT A or B". Which is exactly what $H_\lor(H_\neg(a),b)$ is.